# Rails 4 many-to-many querying both ways

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between two models - Teams and Tournaments.

When I query to get teams participation in a tournament by calling @tournament.teams i get the expected results.

When I'm trying it the other way around by calling @team.tournaments, to get a list of tournaments in which the team is participation I'm getting the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tournaments.team_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `tournaments`.* FROM `tournaments` WHERE `tournaments`.`team_id` = 2
```

How can I make this work? I suppose it's a simple fix, but I'm just a beginner and can't seem to figure it out myself.

EDIT:

Team model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_teams
  has_many :users, :through => :user_teams

  has_many :teams_in_tournaments
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :teams_in_tournaments
  has_many :tournaments

  belongs_to :team_leader, class_name: "User"
  has_many :matches
end
```

Tournament model:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams_in_tournaments
  has_many :teams, :through => :teams_in_tournaments
  belongs_to :organizer, class_name: "User"
  has_one :rule, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rule
  has_many :matches, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: "Team"
end
```

Comment: what are you using? `has_many :through` or `HABTM`

Comment: has_many :through

Comment: Is there a team_id column on tournaments table?

Comment: there is in the join table, as it is the other way around as well

Comment: can you please add the associations and the model code

Comment: I believe somethings wrong with associations

Comment: added just now :)

Comment: ok, already figured it out. I needed to change the name of the second association to the same model. Pretty obvious after all ;)